# Removing nodes using Feeds module

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I am using [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module (7.x-2.0-alpha8) to create nodes with CSV import.

Currently following patch [Unpublish/Delete nodes not included in feed](https://drupal.org/node/1470530) only provides the feature where if the entry is not there in the feed than delete the corresponding node.

However the above requirement doesn't seems to solve my problem. Following is my requirement

Under the CSV file I have one column called **Delete**, which stores Boolean value. If the entry has to be deleted than the value is 1 otherwise 0.

I wonder how it can be resolved. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I want to do the same for users.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hook that checks for this field (which you'd have to add to the content type that you're importing into) then delete the node if its set to 1.  In order for this to work you would need to specify a field as unique otherwise feeds wouldn't know what item that already exists is to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing you can do that doesn't require writing a custom module: map your `Delete` column with a custom field, and then use [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to select all nodes with that `field == 1` and delete them.

If you don't want to create an extra field, you can use the default `Published status` field:

[image: Field status: Published]

You'll need to change the value of the `Delete` column in your CSV to '0' for status Unpublished and '1' for Published. Use VBO to select all Unpublihsed nodes, and delete them.